# Ошибка обращения к переменной из обработчика события System.Timer

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в WPF использовать таймер?

Получаю ошибку:

> InvalidOperationException was not handled by user code.
>
> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

[image]

Comment: Возможно, следует преобразовать value в int. Насколько я помню, в C# всё что в формах - строка.

Comment: Сделал, но ошибка осталась.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.100).aspx). Так

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(() => progressBar1.Value++)
);
```

Либо код, который приведен по ссылке в статье на MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

В WPF нужно пользоваться DispatcherTimer вместо Timer. Он будет работать в нужном потоке.