# Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток

Tags: c#, wpf

На строке:

```
node.name_ = textBlockHead.Text;
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в
>   WindowsBase.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к
>   данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой
>   поток.

```
TimerCallback timeCB = new TimerCallback(TimerForNodeSave);

            Timer time = new Timer(timeCB, null, 0, 10000);

void TimerForNodeSave(object state)
        {
            NodeSave(null, null);
        }

void NodeSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
...
SaveTextTo(GLOBAL.node_old);

void SaveTextTo(Node node)
        {
            node.name_ = textBlockHead.Text;
```

Comment: Как правильно подсказывают, это дубликат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы должны обращаться к UI-элементам только из главного потока. Судя по всему, `textBlockHead` у вас UI-элемент. Чтобы прочитать значение из него, делайте как-то так:

```
void SaveTextTo(Node node)
{
    string text = null;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => text = textBlockHead.Text);
    node.name_ = text;
}
```

Но правильнее было бы воспользоваться async/await и радикально упростить код:

```
async Task RunPeriodicSave()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        var text = textBlockHead.Text
        SaveTextTo(GLOBAL.node_old, text);
    }
}
```

А если `SaveTextTo` медленный, то

```
        await Task.Run(() => SaveTextTo(GLOBAL.node_old, text));
```

Comment: Вроде где-то был каноничный вопрос на эту тему? Можно было закрыть как копию.

Comment: @andreycha: Ага, я беглым поиском не нашёл. Но вообще дубликат, конечно.

Comment: @andreycha: Вот есть, но он не очень каноничный: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/106006/10105

Comment: @andreycha: О, нашёл: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418461/10105

Comment: Да, именно. Надо бы подобные вопросы себе в закладки добавлять, чтоб под рукой были ).

Comment: @andreycha: Хорошая идея :)